# Instalar PHP 7 no servidor Linux AWS EC2

Tags: php, linux, amazon-aws

Estou executando o seguinte comando:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

O meu intuito é instalar o PHP, porém esta voltando o erro:

```
>Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
>Construindo árvore de dependências       
>Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
>E: Impossível encontrar o pacote php7
>E: Impossível encontrar o pacote libapache2-mod-php7
>E: Impossível encontrar o pacote php7-mcrypt
```

Não estou achando nada na internet sobre.

O que devo fazer para concluir a instalação de meu servidor php?

Comment: não sei se já ouviu falar do LAMP (Linux, Apache, Mysql e PHP). se for essa sua intenção (instalar todos eles), dá uma olhada aqui -> http://lamphowto.com/

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver com algumas dicas.

A primeira é existe um comando para verificar quais versões do PHP tem disponivel, para efetuar este comando basta :

```
$ sudo apt-cache search php
```

Assim descobri que era preciso efetuar o comando assim:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt
```

Fazendo isto conseguir instalar normalmente o meu php7.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
sudo  amazon-linux-extras | grep php
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable php7.4
sudo yum clean metadata
sudo yum install httpd php
```

Substitua o `yum` por `apt-get` dependendo do sistema